# Delphi and indy TIDHTTP : distinguish between "server not found" and "not found" response error

Tags: delphi, indy

I am using indy TIDHTTP to code a way to know whether my server on the internet is down or the address of the page on the same server is not available.

I copied the suggestion given in another thread on stackoverflow:

```
try
  IdHTTP1.Get(mypage_address);
except
  on E: EIdHTTPProtocolException do begin
     if e.errorcode=404 then
        showmessage('404 File not found');
    // use E.ErrorCode, E.Message, and E.ErrorMessage as needed...
  end;
end;
```

but this way I am only able to detect a server response code and not whether the server did not respond at all. I guess it's trivial but I do not know what is the way to do that?

Comment: You could either try by using a non-existing URL like http://www.example.com, or checking the source code of Indy. In Indy, EIdHTTPProtocolException can be thrown as the result of a HTTP GET request only if the server has been found and has actually sent a response.

Comment: Hi, how connecting to a non-existing url can tell me anything about my server being down on the internet? Maybe you were confused by my initial question, I have edited hoping it's more clear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An `EIdHTTPProtocolException` exception is raised when `TIdHTTP` successfully sends a request to the server and it sends an HTTP error reply back to `TIdHTTP`.  If the server cannot be reached at all, a different exception (typically `EIdSocketError`, `EIdConnectException`, or `EIdConnectTimeout`) will be raised instead.

```
try
  IdHTTP1.Head(mypage_address);
except
  on E: EIdHTTPProtocolException do begin
    ShowMessage(Format('HTTP Error: %d %s', [E.ErrorCode, E.Message]));
  end;
  on E: EIdConnectTimeout do begin
    ShowMessage('Timeout trying to connect');
  end;
  on E: EIdSocketError do begin
    ShowMessage(Format('Socket Error: %d %s', [E.LastError, E.Message]));
  end;
  on E: Exception do begin
    ShowMessage(Format('Error: [%s] %s', [E.ClassName, E.Message]));
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks, can you also help me finding the units where EIdConnectTimeout and EIdSocketError are defined?

Comment: `EIdConnectTimeout` is in the `IdExceptionCore` unit. `EIdSocketError` is in the `IdStack` unit.

Answer (score 1):

I attempted doing the server/site checking scientifically. but eventually simply came down to this:

```
function TFrameSiteChecker.GetSiteHeader(const AUrl: string): Integer;
begin
  try
    idhttp1.Head(AUrl);
    Result := idhttp1.ResponseCode;
  except
    on E: exception do
      Result := 0;
  end;
end;
```

Logic being, getting the head reduces traffic, log sizes etc.

There is one one right result from the function - the return of status code 200, anything else is a fail.

Also I failed to force windows / the system / indy to not buffer/cache content, so also eventually, just run the checker every 30 minutes on a schedule. Otherwise (unless something else clears the cache) after the first connect it always succeeds, even if you unplug the machine from the network!

Comment: Hi, thanks. I am not very familiar with the TIdHttp.Head method. Does the url passed need to be of type: http://www.mydomain.com or can it be any page, such as: http://www.mydomain.com/test/script.php ?

Comment: any page should provide a response to HEAD - you are simply retrieving the page HTML HEADER, between <HEAD> and </HEAD> rather than the whole page.

Comment: @Despatcher: That is NOT what `TIdHTTP.Head()` does.  It requests the server to send only the HTTP headers for the page and no body content at all. It is a good way to check for a page's existence without retrieving the page itself.

Comment: Sorry must be tired or gettin' old. No page content (as I said, confusingly) it just gets the headers thereby checking the page is accessible

Comment: @Despatcher: yes, it retrieves the HTTP headers, not the HTML headers. Big difference.